# Anchor point not working in jquery popup

Tags: jquery, popup

Here is my fiddle code.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdfET/3/

```
$(function() {
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
  }
});
```

The pop up is opening fine. Inside it, there are 2 sections. I want to assign anchor points to those 2 sections inside the pop up so when I click on "help 1", it should go to "Title 1 come here" and when I click on "help 2", it should go to "Title 2 come here". But currently it is not working as I want. Anchor points are working fine on same page but not in pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/qdfET/4/

```
$(function () {

    ...

    $('.Link10ptNormal').click(function () {
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        var container = $( ".content" ).find('div:first');
        var anc = container.find('a[name="'+$(this).attr('href').replace('#','')+'"]');
        container.animate({'scrollTop' : anc.position().top }, 2000 );
        //instead of above line, if you don't want animation use following line
        //container.scrollTop(anc.position().top);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Play around the .top value for more accurate result. Like

```
container.animate({'scrollTop' : anc.position().top - 30 }, 2000 );
```